# React slick-slider wheel Event for child components (useRef)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-slick

Im using the React slick-slider. I wanted to implement the wheel event so when the user scrolls on the trackpad it would change the current slide. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-slick-slider-issues I'm using the `useRef` to make a reference to the slider and then calling the slick functions inside the event listener callback.

It was fine when it was just one child component, but when out of curiosity I added the same child in the parent below the initial reference. the `slickNext` and `slickPrev` are called for both the sliders. is it due to the way I'mm using the `useRef` or is there any way to only call the slick functions when the user is on that slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're listening on `window.addEventListener` which means that wherever the user scrolls, both of the sliders are firing `slickNext` and `slickPrev`.

if you want to trigger those functions for each Slider, you should listen to `scroll` on the component's root itself.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!parentRef.current) {
    return;
  }
  parentRef.current.addEventListener('wheel', (e)=>handleScroll(e));

  return (() => {
    parentRef.current.removeEventListener('wheel',(e)=>handleScroll(e));
  });
}, [parentRef, rowData]);
```

```html
<div ref={parentRef} style={{ backgroundColor: "green", height: "140px" }}>
  {...}
</div>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-slick-slider-issues-xunhy3?file=ReactSlider.js